# Robust regression - differences in approach (rlm and lmrob)?

Tags: r, regression, robust, lm, rlm

I am looking to implement robust regression in R for large data (n=~500,000). The two options that come up are `lmrob` and `rlm`. When I used lmrob, it gave me the following error:

```
Error in lmrob.S(x, y, control = control) : 
  Fast S large n strategy failed. Use control parameter 'fast.s.large.n = Inf'.
```

I changed the parameter `fast.s.large.n` to `Inf`. But after running for 
4-5 hours, it ended with a warning:

```
Warning messages:
1: In lmrob.S(x, y, control = control) :
  S refinements did not converge (to refine.tol=1e-07) in 200 (= k.max) steps
```

I switched to `rlm`. Unfortunately, it gave an error as well:

```
Error in rlm.default(x, y, weights, method = method, wt.method = wt.method,  : 
  'x' is singular: singular fits are not implemented in 'rlm'
```

I followed the suggestion on this forum to leave some categorical variables as characters in the data frame rather than converting to `factor`. I re-ran `rlm` and it completed within less than a minute.

I am not sure if the results of `rlm` I obtained can be trusted. One, the rlm took a fraction of time that `lmrob` took. Two, the categorical variables are left as characters, instead of factors.

Are `lmrob` and `rlm` this drastically different for the same purpose of robust regression?

Comment: Please add answer on `Are lmrob and rlm this drastically different for the same purpose of robust regression?` if you found it and please tag me here. Thank you